# HUZZAH ESP-8266 (by ADAFRUIT): How to use with the ARDUINO R3

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266, adafruit

I have recently purchased a ESP-8266 HUZZAH by adafruit. I'm kind of new to the whole arduino concept. I would like to know how I would be able to utilise this breakout board with my Arduino to do anything. I have searched on the internet and I know about flashing the board. However, I have no idea how to flash this device. Some help would be appreciated.

I also have no idea where to put my pins. I know that there are RX and TX pins on the UNO, but those are at 0 and 1. Most online guides are using something like 11/12 or 2/3.

[Here](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2471) is the link to the product website

Thanks,
Vraj

Comment: You wouldn't typically use it with an Uno. You program the ESP8266 directly with your own code and interface it to your devices of choice.

Comment: Oh ok. But would I still be able to use it with an arduino. I'm asking because I don't want to immediately go out and buy a new board if the old one works.

Comment: You can use it "with" an Arduino if you want to use it with an Arduino. You need some form of USB to UART device to program it, and the Arduino can do that. Just connect RESET to GND on the Arduino to disable the Arduino, then pins 0/1 can link your computer to the Huzzah.

Comment: Thanks, one other thing. I have a working MFRC522, I want to send the data from the RFID Card to the WiFi board to put it onto a website/server. If I connect it to the arduino and shut the arduino down. Would this still be possible?

Comment: No. You would connect the MFRC522 directly to the Huzzah. The Arudino is just the equivalent of an FT232 board. It's a dumb pipe. If you want to connect the MFRC522 to the Arduino then you will also have to write software for bothe the Arduino and the Huzzah to communicate between them (probably over serial).

Comment: Woah. That's weird. So I found this thing on the MFRC522 github post. It states that it is compatible with the ESP8266. So now that I have some info on that, what's the deal about the flashing thing. Would I still have to perform the flash? And how would I do that? Sorry, just very confused...

Comment: "Flashing" is the act of uploading your software to the ESP8266 from the Arduino IDE. It's how you get your code into the chip to make it do what you want it to do.

Comment: Oh yes. I see thank you. So that's what the posts meant. I think I have a deeper knowledge of the topic. Once I can fully get the solution, I'll post it as an answer. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, I'll keep this post open for anyone who got this board and the Arduino and wanted to use them together (it's probably only me, but who cares). Anyway, when looking at this board it's basically it's own controller. The front pins are what you need to communicate with the board itself. It's meant to be used with a FTDI cable to the computer. Anyway, looking further into it we see many pins behind the first 6 or so. To connect it to the computer using the Arduino you need to use this config.

```
Arduino | HUZZAH ESP8266
RX | RX (In the front)
TX | TX (In the front)
5V | V+ (In the front)
GND | GND (In the front)
```

Also, you need to create a thing where the Arduino won't be able to function, making it a communicator port for the HUZZAH itself. To do this simply take one of the GND pins on the Arduino and connect it to the RESET pin on the Arduino. After doing this you need to set up your ESP8266. [This](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-huzzah-esp8266-breakout/using-arduino-ide) is a link to a basic guide on how to do this by ADAFRUIT. Instead of the USB cable, you are using your arduino as a cable essentially (a pretty expensive one). Anyway, the port number should be the port that your arduino is connected to (to the computer). This is if you want to use the ARDUINO IDE.

To use NODEMCU LUA which it comes preloaded with, you need to refer to [this](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-huzzah-esp8266-breakout/using-nodemcu-lua) guide.

The other thing I wanted to mention was how to utilise a basic board with the controller. I had to use a MFRC522 RFID board with the Arduino, and I wanted to send the info to the internet. Sadly, it seemed as if I couldn't use the arduino itself. To use this board I used many sources. First, was the library github ([this](https://github.com/miguelbalboa/rfid) one).

The next step was to get the pin layout (from [here](https://github.com/miguelbalboa/rfid#pin-layout)). However, if you look at it it's in the pin format of a WESMOS D1 MINI board. The final source was to look at the product page ([here](https://wiki.wemos.cc/products:d1:d1_mini)) and convert the pin format to fit the HUZZAH Board (It's in the PIN section). That took a long time, but now you're done. That's a basic guide on how I used the HUZZAH Board with my arduino.